# form not rendering

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using zend framework and am trying to output a simple login form using zend form, MVC and OOP.

My code is below:
The Controller
IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->loginForm = $this->getLoginForm(); 
    }

    public function getLoginForm()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Login;
        return $form;
    }
}
```

This is the form:
Login.php

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $form = new Zend_Form;

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username
            ->setLabel('Username')
            ->setRequired(true)
        ;

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password
            ->setLabel('Password')
            ->setRequired(true)
        ;

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Login');

        $form->addElements(array($username, $password, $submit));

    }
}
```

And the view:
index.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="../application/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->loginForm; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to Zend Framework, MVC and OOP, So this my best attempt at this following online advice, tutorials etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have inadvertently created a form with no elements, which is why nothing is appearing. In the init method of your form object you are creating a new instance of `Zend_Form`, `$form` which you then do nothing with, instead of adding the elements to the current instance. Change your class to this:

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username
            ->setLabel('Username')
            ->setRequired(true)
        ;

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password
            ->setLabel('Password')
            ->setRequired(true)
        ;

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Login');

        $this->addElements(array($username, $password, $submit));
    }
}
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this instead:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html